# Django many-to-many relations, and through

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I want to store which user invited another user to a group... but django is telling me this is ambigous and against the rules (which makes sense).

> groups.group: Intermediary model
>   Group_to_Member has more than one
>   foreign key to User, which is
>   ambiguous and is not permitted.

So how do I do this correctly? Maybe a generic relation? might work but seems a bit convoluted... Here's how I was approaching it (with unrelated bits removed)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserGroup(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Group_to_Member')

class UserGroup_to_Member(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(UserGroup)
    member = models.ForeignKey(User)

    invited_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="group_invited_users")
```

### Solution

Ok so I did a little combination of the answers you guys provided (Thanks!) and things I found on the internet plus my own admittedly meager python-fu:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserGroup(models.Model):
    # notice there is no member object here
    ... other model data

    def add_member(self, **kwargs):
        g2m = UserGroup_to_Member(group = self,  **kwargs)
        g2m.save()

    def remove_member(self, member):
        g2m = UserGroup_to_Member.objects.get(group=self, member=member)
        g2m.delete()

    # This is not elegant at all, help please? I'm pretty sure it isn't
    # as bad on the database as it looks though.
    def get_members(self):
        g2ms = UserGroup_to_Member.objects.filter(group=self)
        member_ids = [g2m.member.id for g2m in g2ms]
        members = User.objects.none()
        for id in member_ids:
            members = members | User.objects.get(id=id)
        return members

class UserGroup_to_Member(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(UserGroup)
    member = models.ForeignKey(User)

    invited_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="group_invited_users")
```

Comment: There's this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583327/django-model-with-2-foreign-keys-from-the-same-table

Comment: @seth, it's not a matter of adding a related_name, the issue is that there are 2 foreignkey relations to User, it doesn't matter what I call them or if I set a related_name

Comment: The other one had the exact same problem as you (i.e. 2 foreign keys on the same table) so I thought it would help.  My django-fu is kind of raw though so perhaps I misunderstood your question.  Do you have the DB set up?  Why not just run inspectdb on it and see what models it generates? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

Comment: From the docs (from  the last answer on that other question) it would appear that what you want to do is not possible out of the box. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got a solution pieced together

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to manage it yourself:

```
class MyGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(MyGroup)
    member = models.ForeignKey(User)

    invited_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='invited_set')
```

Then instead of `group.members.all()` you do `group.membership_set.all()`.

Also, I wouldn't use 'Group' as your model name, as Django already has a Group object.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the model name, but your solution does not use a many-to-many relation

Comment: also... group.members.all() returns a queryset of User objects, whereas group.membership_set.all() returns a queryset of Membership objects

Comment: the only way to get a list of group members using that method is member_list = [m.member for m in Membership.objects.filter(group=group)]

Comment: You're having it wrong. You're looking for Users, so you have to go through the User model (or a custom manager). Therefore, you should  use `members = User.objects.filter(

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you are using Django 1.7.

From the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

> In Django 1.6 and earlier, intermediate models containing more than
>   one foreign key to any of the models involved in the many-to-many
>   relationship used to be prohibited.