# Automatic solution for "Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'XXX'."?

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

I'm plugging Django into an existing system. I have been given a legacy schema, and I have to work with it.

I have generated models with `inspectdb`, but I'm getting hundreds of:

```
ABC>DEF: Accessor for field 'HIJ' clashes with related field 'KLM'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'HIJ'.
```

I wouldn't have a problem with this if it were only a small number. But it isn't.

Is there any automatic way to fix this by adding unique `related_name`s?

EDIT: For clarification, I do am looking for an automatic solution to the problem, not one that involves editing each field by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the related name, you can [set it to "+"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

If you don't want to disable them completely or cannot use "+" in your django version (I can't remember when it was added), you may use something like the following:

```
_no_related_name_counter = 0
def no_related_name():
    _no_related_name_counter += 1
    return "_norn_%%(class)s_%i" % _no_related_name_counter

ForeignKey(..., related_name=no_related_name())
```

But if you insert related names with a regexp search and replace, you may as well set them to something readable, e.g. replace `(\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*models\.ForeignKey\(.*)\)(\s*)$` with `$1, related_name="%(class)s_$2_reverse")$3`

Comment: Yeah, I have ended up doing textual processing on the source file to add "+". I had hoped there might be something less hacky I could do.

Answer (score 4):

Occasionally I find myself in this situation. Modifying `inspectdb` has worked for me in several instances but I can't promise it'll be appropriate in every situation. Here's what I've done:

```
    #Original inspectdb
    121                         if rel_to in known_models:
    122                             field_type = 'ForeignKey(%s' % rel_to
    123                         else:
    124                             field_type = "ForeignKey('%s'" % rel_to

    #Modified inspectdb
    121                         if rel_to in known_models:
    122                             field_type = 'ForeignKey(%s' % rel_to
    123                         else:
    124                             field_type = "ForeignKey('%s'" % rel_to
    125                         extra_params['related_name'] = '%s_%s' % (table2model(table_name),column_to_field_name[column_name])
```

This will automatically add a `related_name` argument to every generated model that *isn't likely* to collide with any others. Again, it depends on the situation, but this single line modification has saved me tons of work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was 7 years ago and I have long since left this problem, and context behind.

Comment: @Joe Sure thing! I do realize it's a 7 year old conversation :-) I just stumbled across this thread when researching a similar issue and figured somebody else might benefit from what I had to say.

Comment: I was tempted to wait another 7 years before replying... Anyway, thanks for your answer. Hope others find it useful.

Comment: I'm coming from the future and I have to say thanks! This should be the accepted answer. @musashiXXX if you're not going to, can I submit a PR to the django repository on your behalf?

Comment: @SebastiánVansteenkiste I don't think this is quite PR-level, but I certainly have found it to be a useful hack.

Comment: Well, @musashiXXX I actually tried but got shot down because of this ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11179

Comment: @SebastiánVansteenkiste That's an old one... the closing comment kind of sounds like a cop-out but whatever.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still thinking this should be part of the default behaviour but I guess they'd rather not touch the codebase?

Comment: I feel like something like this should make it into django as an option on inspectdb. Maybe somebody can add a PR?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the foreign key relationships by specifying the related_name, like this:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user')
admin = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user1') #you need to use a different related_name here
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not feasible for hundreds of tables. Sorry, I don't think I can be clearer with my question.

Comment: Take a look at this thread then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583327/django-model-with-2-foreign-keys-from-the-same-table

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with large legacy database and dont want to use '+' you can run a simple script to modify the generated models.py file as follows:

```
import fileinput
textToSearch = "models.DO_NOTHING"

_no_related_name_counter = 1000

with fileinput.FileInput('models.py', inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        _no_related_name_counter += 1
        textToReplace = 'models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="%(class)s_{}"'.format(_no_related_name_counter)
        print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace), end='')
```