# Django - Model with 2 foreign keys from the same class

Tags: django, django-models

I wanted a Django model with 2 foreign keys from the same table. It's an event table which has 2 columns for employees: the 'home' and the 'away'. But I get this error: Error: One or more models did not validate...

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Match(models.Model):
    home = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    away = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

Any idea for this. Thanks!

Comment: You may quote the whole error message for future reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I have two foreign keys to the same model in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543377/how-can-i-have-two-foreign-keys-to-the-same-model-in-django)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I have two foreign keys to the same model in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543377/how-can-i-have-two-foreign-keys-to-the-same-model-in-django)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `Match` model to use [`related_name`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

```
class Match(models.Model):
    home = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="home_set")
    away = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="away_set")
```

The documentation has this to say about `related_name`:

> The name to use for the relation from the related object back to this one.

You are getting the error because from the `Team` side there will be two relations and they will both have the name, viz. `match`. You'll refer to this from the `Team` side using `team.match_set`. By changing the `related_name` of the second FK you are fixing this.

**Update**

As @Török Gábor [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736321/django-model-with-2-foreign-keys-from-the-same-class/3736386#3736386), you can now use `team.home_set` and `team.away_set` respectively.

Answer (score 7):

Django follows relationship backwards, too. By default, it creates attribute `match_set` on your `Team` objects. Because you referenced `Team` twice, you must distinguish those backwards attributes by providing [`related_name` attribute](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) on `ForeignKey`s.

```
class Match(models.Model):
    home = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='home_set')
    away = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='away_set')
```

Comment: @Matthew Rankin: it was my mistake, sorry, but corrected it already as I realized.