# Django: How to have a multiple foreign keys references the same table in one table

Tags: database, django

I know that normally Django would create a foreign key called `user_id` if I simply do something like

```
from django.db import models

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('created date')

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

but what if I need three distinct foreign key in `Order` that all points to `User`? The three foreign keys would be `user_created`, `user_modified`, and `user_status`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I have two foreign keys to the same model in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543377/how-can-i-have-two-foreign-keys-to-the-same-model-in-django)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is actually straight forward:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user_status = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders_status')
    user_created = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders_created')
    user_modified = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders_modified')
```

You just need to define separate `related_name`s to avoid ambiguity when accessing the Order from the User object.

Comment: Ok, so your `user` in this case would be `user_status`? Is there a reason why you don't use `related_name` for the first one?

Comment: The first one takes the default related name and is accessed via `user.order_set` - of course, one could also assign a custom related name here as well.

Comment: ...and yes, the first one would be user_status - I overlooked it in your post and updated my answer