# Django check if object in ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have quite a simple problem to solve. I have Partner model which has >= 0 Users associated with it:

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(db_index=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Now, if I have a User object and I have a Partner object, what is the most Pythonic way of checking if the User is associated with a Partner? I basically want a statement which returns True if the `User` is associated to the `Partner`.

I have tried:

```
users = Partner.objects.values_list('user', flat=True).filter(slug=requested_slug)
if request.user.pk in users:
    # do some private stuff
```

This works but I have a feeling there is a better way. Additionally, would this be easy to roll into a decorator, baring in mind I need both a named parameter (`slug`) and a request object (`user`).

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
if user.partner_set.filter(slug=requested_slug).exists():
     # do some private stuff
```

Comment: How to raise http403 in else? Return HttpResponseForbidden throws error

Comment: I'm guessing, since I can't see your full context, but it looks like you're trying to return the class. Instead, you have to instantiate it: `return HttpResponseForbidden()`.

Comment: where is the filtering by a specific partner here?

Comment: @Alex78191 - the OP's example has the desired partner identified by the `slug` attribute. If instead you have EG the partner's ID, `user.partner_set.filter(id=requested_id).exists()` works too. The point is that you can `filter` the user's `partner_set` manager as needed, then use `exists()`.

Comment: what is `partner_set`?

Comment: @Alex78191 - it's the auto-created reverse relationship accessor. Because `Partner` has a relationship to `User`, `User` instances have an accessor attribute `partner_set`. See the docs for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

Comment: What happens to reverse accessor if several relationships with one class are defined?

Comment: You have to define a `related_name` attribute in the relationship field to disambiguate in that case. See for instance this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543377/how-can-i-have-two-foreign-keys-to-the-same-model-in-django/543406

Answer (score 8):

If we just need to know whether a `user` object is associated to a `partner` object, we could just do the following (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388993/1526703)):

```
if user in partner.user.all():
    #do something
```

Comment: Is this faster or slower than Peter's answer?