# How to check if object value in manytomany field?

Tags: python, django

How to check if value is in manytomany field? I am trying to do something like this:

```
if value in object1.followers:
    #BLA BLA BLA
```

But `'ManyRelatedManager' is not iterable`. So what is correct way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot the `all()`:

```
if value in object1.followers.all():
    ...
```