# How can I change the default description of a Django models.ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a django ForeignKey like this

```
class Example(models.Model):
    Field = models.CharField("Description", max_length=50)
    AnotherField = models.CharField("Extra Info", max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Field
```

By default the `HTML select` will contain as description the values of the `Example.Field` field. I can't change the unicode method. The real problem is when I need another values a model. I need something like This:

```
class SecondExapmle(models.Model):
    Description = models.CharField("Description", max_length=50)
    Foreign     = models.ForeignKey(Example)
    SecondData  = models.ForeignKey(Example, show_value_from_column="AnotherField") # this line
```

Suposing that `SecondExample` has the next records:

```
-----------------------------
| id | field | anotherfield |
-----------------------------
| 1  | Str   | Another Str  |
| 2  | Str2  | Another2     |
-----------------------------
```

I need that the Form's Foreign select contains the next HTML:

```
<select id="id_foreign">
   <option value='1'>Str</option>
   <option value='2'>Str2</option>
</select>
```

And the Forms AnotherField select contains the next HTML:

```
<select id="id_anotherfield">
   <option value='1'>Anotheer Str</option>
   <option value='2'>Another2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried the `help_text` keyword argument for `ForiegnKey`? So, `ForeignKey(Example, help_text="AnotherField")`.

Comment: Without a related_name this model will be invalid as the Example model is related twice from SecondExample, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543377/how-can-i-have-two-foreign-keys-to-the-same-model-in-django)

Comment: Is true that I need to set the related name, but I need to set a different descripion in the selects. The `help_text` only will add an static value to the `title` property of the `HTML select`

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `forms.ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) - which is the field that is used for a ForeignKey on a form - shows exactly what to do here. You need to subclass the form field and define a `label_from_instance` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `verbose_name=''`:

```
models.ForeignKey(Example, verbose_name='Example')
```