# Django ForeignKey in same table about same attribute in different table

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-database, django-related-manager

I have one model in my project.

```
class users(models.Model):
   match_user    = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   matched_user    = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Imagine that: match_user is 'Mete' and matched_user is 'Gizem'. Also match_user is 'Gizem' and matched_user is 'Mete' I have 2 table line:

```
id       match_user    matched_user
__       __________    ____________
1        mete          gizem
2        gizem         mete
```

Now if ı want delete mete, only first row deleted. But I want to delete 2 rows.Actually I want to two foreign key about same location in different table. How I can? is it possible. İf it is not a possible, is there any solution for my want.
Also I tried some different ways like that:

```
match_user    = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="username"on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
matched_user    = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="username",on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
```

But there is error all time
Thanks for answers :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543377/how-can-i-have-two-foreign-keys-to-the-same-model-in-django

Comment: I saw this questions. But my wrong is related_name is wrong place in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by specifying different [**`related_name`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) as,

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    match_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_users')
    matched_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='matched_users')
```